# I'm a beginner to threejs - how can I turn this shader (that uses gl_fragcoord) to a geometry's material to have the same effect?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this shader code

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

vec3 vary(vec3 y)
{
    y = y+sin(u_time*1.5)*y.r;
    return y;
}

void main()
{
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    vec3 color = vary(vec3(st.x*1.65, st.y*1.,1.));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
```

You can see the effect of it here.
http://editor.thebookofshaders.com/

(with the code above pasted - the export wasn't working for some reason)

As you can see it's a sort of moving color shader, that depends on the coordinates of the fragment. The value for "u_resolution that I passed in is

```
uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
```

These change every time the scene window is changed.

So the problem is that I don't know how to turn the effect of this shader to a THREEJS geometry (a cube for instance) to display. I know how to display THREEJS, what stumps me is this shader. Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to pass the texture coordinates from the geometry from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

Create a vertex shader which pass through the texture coordinates:

```c
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Use the texture coordinates (`vUv.xy`) in the fragment shader instead of `gl_FragCoord.xy`:

```c
precision highp float;
uniform float u_time;
varying vec2 vUv;

vec3 vary(vec3 y)
{
    y = y+sin(u_time*1.5)*y.r;
    return y;
}

void main(){
    vec2 st = vUv;
    vec3 color = vary(vec3(st.x*1.65, st.y*1.,1.));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
```

See the example:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var loader, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls, uniforms;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -2);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();

  }

  function createModel() {

    uniforms = {
        u_time : { type: 'f', value: 100 }
    };
        
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate(deltaT) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render(deltaT);
  }

  function render(deltaT) {
    uniforms.u_time.value = deltaT / 1000.0;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
precision highp float;
uniform float u_time;
varying vec2 vUv;

vec3 vary(vec3 y)
{
    y = y+sin(u_time*1.5)*y.r;
    return y;
}

void main(){
    vec2 st = vUv;
    vec3 color = vary(vec3(st.x*1.65, st.y*1.,1.));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
</script>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! It worked flawlessly. One question though: through my understanding of gl_fragcoord and passing the resolution of the screen, I could get the coordinates of the screen normalized between [0,1]. So because I'm using the projectionmatrix to get the scene in clip space between [0,1] (i think), that's why I was able to use just the uv coordinates which has the same effect for a geometry?

Comment: @total If you darw a rectangular plane on the entire screen, the the uv coordinates are the same as `gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution`. [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) contains the window relative coordinate of the fragment (in pixel)